# Scheme list counting function

Tags: list, recursion, count, scheme

I'm trying to write a Scheme function that counts all the items in a list, but unlike the length function that is available would count inner lists also so countAll '(a (a b)) would return 3 and not 2.

the first check is for an empty list, the second is supposed to check if the head of the list is currently a list itself, it should then add the length of THAT list to the total and call the next recursive call, if it isn't, it should simply skip to the third part which will add one to the total and call the function recursively.

I'm getting syntactical errors and I'm unsure about my approach. Am I going about this the right way? Are there better/Easier ways to do this?

```
(define countAll 
  (lambda (list)

    (if (null? list)
        0

        ((if (list? (car list)
                    (+ length (car list)
                       (countAll (cdr list))))))

        (+ 1
           (countAll (cdr list))))))     
  (+ 1
   (countAll(cdr list)
  )))))
```

Comment: I've edited the question to introduce indentation according to the structure of the program.  The fact that the indentation is so weird should be a hint that the program structure is not quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a mess of your parentheses.  I would strongly advise rewriting this using **cond**, as in

```
(cond
  ((null? lst) 0)
  ((list? (car lst)) (???))
  (else (???)))
```

This will make it easier to see what you are doing and much less likely that you mess up your parentheses.  Nested ifs really are something to avoid except in the simplest of circumstances.

Your approach is *nearly* right, but you've missed something.  You have made a *big* assumption about what happens when `(list? (car lst))` evaluates to true.  Can you think what it is?  If you think about it hard enough, you'll realise that you cannot use the **length** function here.

Comment: If the original function input was say (a (a b c) d) for example,

On the first pass, both evaluations would fail and recursion would occur, making the input to the next iteration ( (a b c) d)

As far as I understand (list? (car lst)) should evaluate (a b c) from the previous list, then the length function will count it. if it's not a list, the code won't execute. What am I missing!?

Comment: What is going to happen with `'(a (a (a b) c) d)`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this kind of problem follows a well-known structure, a recipe if you wish, for traversing a list of lists. This looks like homework, so I'll help you with the general idea and you go ahead filling-in the blanks:

```
(define (countAll lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)               ; if the list is empty.
         <???>)                    ; then it doesn't have any elements
        ((not (list? (car lst)))   ; if the first element in the list is not a list
         (<???> (countAll <???>))) ; add one and advance the recursion over the `cdr`
        (else                      ; otherwise
         (+ (countAll <???>)       ; add the result of the recursion over the `car`
            (countAll <???>)))))   ; with the result of the recursion over the `cdr`
```

If you need more help understanding how to structure a solution to this kind of problems dealing with lists of lists, I'd recommend you take a look at either [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) or [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), both books will teach you how to grok recursive processes in general.

Comment: I thought `pair?` will only return true if it's exactly two values? eg. `(pair? '(1 2))` -> `#t`, `(pair? '(1 2 3))` -> `#f`?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Then you managed to ignore all the documentation.  Lists are essentially chained pairs.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas nope, `pair?` returns `true` if the argument passed is a `cons`-cell. In particular, any non-null list is a pair.

Comment: Oscar, I think your answer is *too* helpful, in the context.  You've gone and explicitly shown how to do something that I've asked him to think about.  You could at least have given him some time to reflect.

Comment: And yet the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) says "A pair combines exactly two values," which is why I am confused by its use.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, just read a couple of paragraphs down that same page and you're shown explicitly that **pair?** returns true for a list longer than two.  You're conflating **value** and **atom**.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No problem, it's a simple confusion and it can happen to anyone :) To make it more clear, I replaced `pair?` with `list?`, it works fine in this example because we already tested to see if the list was `null?`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count elements of nested list you can use the deep recursion function as some people answer here. or what I do is use racket function (flatten) to make the nested list flat then use recursion on level 1 list as in the following code

```
  (define (howMany ls)
  (if (null? ls)
  0
  (+ 1 (howMany (cdr ( flatten ls  )))))) ; flat the nested list and deal with it as a level 1 list.
```